# What numpy.dot function really do with N-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a small program in python and using the numpy library.
This is just for educational purpose and for fun.
My maths background is poor and I try to understand what's going on with the dot function.

I know what is an array and understand that a matrix is a N-dimensionnal array
I also understand how to make a product of this two types, but it's still not clear when I make the products of two N-dimensionnal arrays.

I'm doing some testing in the terminal and here's what I get :

```
>>> a = [[2, 4], [3, 7], [5, 1]]
>>> b = [[1, 6, 7], [3, 9, 2]]
>>> numpy.dot(a, b)
array([[14, 48, 22],
       [24, 81, 35],
       [ 8, 39, 37]])
```

Please can a math guru help me to interpret this result ?

Tell me if the problem is not clear to you, I'll develop if necessary.

**Edit:**

To be more precise about my testing methodology, one of this tests was to apply the dot function on a N-D array and a 1-D array:

```
>>> a = [[2, 4], [3, 7], [5, 1]]
>>> b = [1, 6]
>>> numpy.dot(a, b)
array([26, 45, 11])
```

And here is my comprehension of this:
"b" length must be the same length as any of the "a" subset, if not shapes are not aligned

And the result is calculated like that:

```
[a[0][0] * b[0] + a[0][1] * b[1], 
 a[1][0] * b[0] + a[1][1] * b[1], 
 a[2][0] * b[0] + a[2][1] * b[1]]
```

Comment: It's just matrix-multiplication, right? What exactly is the confusing part?

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html

Comment: @Divakar I just edited my question.

Comment: @wwii thank you, I'll take a look at that article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically multiplying two matrices (arrays). In order to multiply two matrices A and B, A must be of dimension `m x n` and B must be of dimension `n x k`, the result C will be of dimension `m x k` (m rows and k columns).

The result C of A x B in your case is :

```
C(1, 1) = 14 = 2 * 1 + 4 * 3
C(1, 2) =  48 = 2 * 6 + 4 * 9
C(1, 3) = 22 = 2 * 7 + 4 * 2

C(2, 1) = 24 = 3 * 1 + 7 * 3
C(2, 2) =  81 = 3 * 6 + 7 * 9
C(2, 3) = 35 = 3 * 7 + 7 * 2

C(3, 1) = 8 = 5 * 1 + 1 * 3
C(3, 2) =  39 = 5 * 6 + 1 * 9
C(3, 3) = 37 = 5 * 7 + 1 * 2
```

where the matrix C looks like:

```
       |C(1, 1) C(1, 2) C(1, 3)|
C =    |C(2, 1) C(2, 2) C(2, 3)|
       |C(3, 1) C(3, 2) C(3, 3)|
```

Most people get confused about the difference between the dot product and the element-wise multiplication.

**Explanation of element-wise multiplication**

Suppose we have to matrices of the **same shape (i.e. both of dimension m*k)** A and B resulting in a matrix D, then:

```
D(1, 1) = A(1, 1) * B(1, 1)
D(1, 2) = A(1, 2) * B(1, 2)
D(1, 3) = A(1, 3) * B(1, 3)
D(2, 1) = A(2, 1) * B(2, 1)
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks @hallaksec as I said before my algebra knowledge is poor and your explaination helps me a lot to understand the ins and outs. But in the last part of your answer is a little bit confusing to me. What is a "element-wise multiplication" ?

Comment: @TwystO I've edited the post to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification @hallaksec. I was confused indeed. That's why the following error has been raised while executing one of my tests :  
`>>> a = [[2, 4], [3, 7], [5, 1]]`  
`>>> b = [[1, 6], [7, 3], [9, 2]]`  
`>>> numpy.dot(a, b)`  
`Traceback (most recent call last):`  
`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`  
`ValueError: shapes (3,2) and (3,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)`

Comment: @TwystO A must be of dimension `m x n` and B must be of dimension `n x k`, so the number of columns in A must be equal to the number of rows in B which is not the case in your example above.